# lat_ts on Plate Carree in cartopy

Tags: cartopy

I have data with this spatial reference in proj4 format:

+proj=eqc +lat_ts=8 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=180 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=1737400 +b=1737400 +units=m +no_def

As I understand it, `+proj=eqc` is the Plate Carree (equidistant cylindrical) [as described here](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/crs/projections.html#cartopy.crs.PlateCarree).

However, that doesn't take a `lat_ts` parameter (latitude at true scale). Can anyone explain why, and how I can express this coordinate system in cartopy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't currently express that parameter for Equidistant Cyclindrical in Cartopy. The PlateCarree projection in CartoPy has some weird behavior [as well.](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/709) If this is important to you, I'd suggest opening an issue, or better yet, contributing a Pull Request to add Equidistant Cylindrical as a proper projection to CartoPy.